# Contact Form 7: wpcf7_form_response_output filter

Tags: wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

May I ask how is the wpcf7_form_response_output filter (found in includes/contact-form.php) use?

The below is what I had tried but to no avail.

============== **Case 1** ============

**Function 1:**

```
$wpcf7->skip_mail = true;
$content = __('You have already subscribed to our Events.',CURRENT_THEME);
$class = 'wpcf7-validation-errors';
custom_wpcf7_form_response_output_filter('', $class, $content, '');
```

**Function 2**

```
if(!function_exists('custom_wpcf7_form_response_output_filter')){
    function custom_wpcf7_form_response_output_filter($output, $class, $content, $this){
        return '<div class="' . $class . ' ">' . $content . '</div>';
    }
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'custom_wpcf7_form_response_output_filter', 10, 4);
}
```

========== **Case 2** ==============

```
$wpcf7->skip_mail = true;
$class = 'wpcf7-validation-errors';
$error = __('You have already subscribed to our Events.',CURRENT_THEME);
$output = '<div class="' . $class . ' ">' . esc_html( $error ) . '</div>';
$omsg = 'return "'. $output .'";';
add_filter('wpcf7_form_response_output', create_function('$a', $omsg));
```

Case 2: Another method which does not work as well. 500 Internal Server Error when used.

Any help here?

Comment: What happens when you use function 2 ?

Comment: "Your message was sent successfully. Thanks." will be shown instead.
Seems like the filter did not take effect.

Comment: I just looked at the code for CF7, the filter exists .. Can you remove the `if` block and try returning a blank string like `return " "; ` ?

Comment: "Your message was sent successfully. Thanks." message was shown again. No change.

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using ?

Comment: Ver 4.1.1. Will try your suggested functions now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the hook is not attached / triggering at the right time.

**EDIT**

The hook described in this thread does not trigger reliably when making an AJAX call. We decided to do it with JS instead. Here is some code that will help anyone else looking/facing a similar issue

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    str=$(".wpcf7-response-output").html();
    if (str.indexOf("error") >= 0)
        $(".wpcf7-response-output")
            .removeClass("wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")
            .addClass("wpcf7-validation-errors");
    });
```

Comment: "Your message was sent successfully. Thanks." message was shown.
Doesn't take effect.

Comment: Trying inform user if he/she has already subscribed to the event with the same email.

I was informed by the plugin author to use this filter so I can get the message to show in red instead of green after checking.

Comment: I figured out whats happening, the filter works differently than what I expected, it initially has a class and a message but when the form is submitted it is over written by AJAX. Try my new solution and you'll understand why

Comment: Same issue occurred. The class shouldn't be removed, otherwise I would not be able to change the style of the output message accordingly.

Comment: Not really. Is that a way for me to achieve my objective without editing the plugin's file?

Comment: thanks for the solution (https://gist.github.com/JudeRosario/cb92287e64c1bda193e5).

It works now.